# MS Access Query : Consolidate rows with same data in Specific Field Columns

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

i have ms access query with several fields and columns, some of the data in the tables that I query shows up multiple times. I would Like to eliminate duplicates based on 4 columns - if this 4 columns are identical in more rows I would like them to be displayed only one time. Is this possible?
See attached example: [image]
the first 2 entries should be consolidated into 1 entry.

Br,

Comment: Why not just use grouping ? (The Sigma sign in the querybuilder, group by those fields...) - you have to decide what you want to do with the other fields thoug: take the first, highest etc. value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution for this - What I needed to do is to change the property in the Query Design "Unique Values: Yes"